# Kitchen Faucet Cap

Tags: plumbing

Trying to replace a Moen kitchen faucet cartridge on a single lever faucet. The cap which is supposed to be pried off with a screwdriver seems to be frozen. I don't want to scratch it is oil rubbed bronze. Any suggestions?

Comment: Vinegar mighty loosen Ca deposits.

Answer (score 1):

Moen will send free replacements for any damaged part or part that needs to be replaced to keep your faucet working right, including the cap and cartridge. I damaged the cap on mine while trying to remove it and they sent me a free one. It might help to have them send you a parts list and exploded diagram before you go prying on it.